# Fastest method to determine my PC's IP address (Windows)

Tags: windows, ip-address, clipboard

This may seem trivial but I'm looking for the quickest method to determine my PC's IP address **within my network**.

- This changes regularly as I connect from one network to the next via DHCP
- The connection changes from wired to wireless
- Windows 7 PC (although *ideally* the perfect solution would work on all versions of Windows)
- Various adapters installed (e.g. VMWare, Tunnels, etc.)

I need to know this as I often run a local web server where I need to access files over the local network... and since it changes regularly I want the fastest method to retrieve the address.

**My current flow is:**

1. <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog
2. "cmd" + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a command prompt
3. "ipconfig" + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the diagnostics info
4. Scroll to or resize the window so that I can see the line in my Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection for my ipv4 Address
5. Remember it to type elsewhere... or
6. Right click > select **Mark** > highlight the address > press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy it to the clipboard

This wasn't so bad with Windows XP when I had no additional adapters, tunnels, wireless connections etc. but the amount of data returned with this command makes it hard to pluck out.

Surely there **must** be a better, faster way! (bonus points if adding it to the clipboard is easily accomplished)

Comment: I usually use `Start`->`Run`: `cmd /k "ipconfig | find "IPv4" | CLIP"`

Comment: Have you considered asking the network administrator for a a static IP assigned by DHCP? This would be a much better solution

Comment: It would be helpful... but alas its many networks and I don't always have such options/permissions.

Comment: @AT, The `/k` would be optional isn't it?

Comment: Take a look at this app as well http://ipaddressinfinity.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Type this into a .bat file. You can then create a shortcut to it and place it in the taskbar, start menu, or assign a hotkey.

```
ipconfig | find "IPv4" | find /V "192.168." | CLIP
```

What it does: First **find** returns all the lines that contain IPv4. If you have multiple network adapters, from example from VMWare, you may want to exclude them. That's where **find /V** comes into play, it finds all lines that do not contain given string. For example, that's what I get after the first find:

```
>ipconfig | find "IPv4"
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 134.32.72.86
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.229.1
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.230.1
```

Finally, **CLIP** copies the output to the clipboard, so you will be left with

```
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 134.32.72.86
```

If that's not enough maybe someone else can refine it with fancy search patterns.

Comment: This is the method I use, the key is in refining the search string for the particular circumstance. But once you have the batch file you are good to go.

Comment: Do this and then set a shortcut key (like CTRL-SHIFT-I) to run it.

Comment: See my solution for a similar approach using AutoHotkey: http://superuser.com/a/382440/100787

Comment: It's unfortunate that this only works for networks with a 192.168.x.x subnet

Comment: I accepted this as the "correct" answer, however it looks like there are several ways to solve this (including the solution I came up with below http://superuser.com/a/382669/2422 )

Comment: +1 for the clip command, which I had somehow never heard of!

Comment: If you have cygwin installed you can add: ipconfig | find "IPv4" | find /V "192.168." | c:\cygwin\bin\gawk '{print $NF} | CLIP

Answer (score 23):

Create a shortcut to [BGinfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557) (a program that shows system information on the Windows background).  Double-click. : )

Answer (score 7):

There seemed to be several solutions to this problem and I even came up with one of my own.

Similar to @iglvzx I too used the [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) utility to create my own utility app.

I've posted the app online here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/177276/ipAddress.exe

I throw my exe into my Startup folder... and it sits quietly waiting until I hit the hotkey:

<kbd>WindowsKey</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

which then brings up this dialog... allowing me to copy the address with a single click... or navigate to another window as the IP address will display on the app tab on the start bar.  I ended up opting out of automatically putting it on the clipboard just in case I had something important on there that I didn't want to accidentally delete.

[image]

Here's the source code I used to get the IP address (it makes a presumption that the %A_IPAddress1% is the correct one (but from my testing it always was)):

```
#SingleInstance
#Persistent

Menu, tray, NoStandard
Menu, tray, add, Exit, ExitAppCompletely

Hotkey, #i, ShowIPAddress
return

ShowIPAddress:
Gui, Add, Text, x50 y8, Your IP Address:
Gui, Add, Edit, x140 y5 ReadOnly vIPAddress, %A_IPAddress1%
Gui, Add, Text, x50 y35 w250 vCopiedStatus,

Gui, Add, Button, x70 y65 w75, &Copy
Gui, Add, Button, x150 y65 w75, &Dismiss
Gui, Show, W290 H100 Center, %A_IPAddress1% - IP Address
return

ButtonCopy:
clipboard = %A_IPAddress1%
GuiControl,, CopiedStatus, Copied %A_IPAddress1% to the clipboard
Sleep, 1000
GuiControl,, CopiedStatus,
Sleep, 500

ButtonDismiss:
GuiClose:
Gui, Destroy
Exit

ExitAppCompletely:
ExitApp
```

Comment: One-liner version with auto-hotkey: inputbox,ipaddr,IP Address,Your IP address is:,,,,,,,,%A_IPAddress1%

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using a netbios hostname instead?

Figure out your computer name, and then try to ping it using that name on a different computer.
You may find you don't need the IP address at all.

You can get the hostname by running the command `hostname` on your machine.

Answer (score 5):

I use [www.whatismyip.org](http://www.whatismyip.org/). Very simple to use, just navigate to the site in your favorite browser and it will display your external IP.

Like any text, just highlight and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to copy.

If you set it as your homepage and put a shortcut in your QuickStart bar, it only takes 1 click and a copy to get your IP on the clipboard

Comment: You can use http://www.ipchicken.com as well.

Comment: Thanks... I've actually used this many times... and it works great to get my external IP address. However I guess I didn't fully clarify myself... as I actually want the 192.168.xxx.yyy address so that within my LAN/WLAN I can connect from one device to another.

Comment: it's better to use google directly, no need to visit an actual website. https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip at the top **Your public IP address is 192.168.0.1**

Comment: -1 It’s your NAT’s public IP, not your private IP/

Comment: @scunliffe then `ipconfig` in a batch file is probably your best bet

Comment: @JeffAtwood whatismyip.org contains only a plain-text version of the IP though, so you can get it from the command line quickly with wget / curl

Comment: @kinokijuf that was not specified when I answered this question. Both addresses are used to access a computer, just one only works within a LAN and one only works outside of an intranet

Comment: This was specified: The OP asked for **his PC** IP.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - google *is* an "actual website" :)

Comment: @warren no, Google is the [start page for the internet](http://www.skrenta.com/2007/01/winnertakeall_google_and_the_t.html)

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - i'll bow to that point :)

Comment: @JeffAtwood: How on earth would someone's public IP address ever be 192.168.0.1? Worst example of a public IP ever.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work on my XP box but on Windows 7 I can limit the info to a single adapter with

```
netsh interface IP show addresses "Local Area Connection" | findstr "IP" | clip
```

Which could go into a batch file

Answer (score 4):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\myusername> ipconfig /all | find "IP Address"
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 16.138.69.121

and

C:\Users\dalvi>ipconfig /all | find "IPv4 Address"
        IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 16.175.22.139(Preferred)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on Amadeu's great answer, here's a variant of that that strips off the beginning part. (must be run as a batch file)

```
@ECHO OFF 

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('ipconfig ^| find "IPv4"') do SET result=%%i

echo %result:IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : =% | clip
```

Answer (score 3):

1. [WindowsKey] IP
2. [Enter] to open "View network connections"
3. Double click on your network
4. Click on "Details"

You can Ctrl+C inside, it will copy whole window content, including the IP addresses

There you go, with four keystrokes and three clicks :)

Answer (score 3):

I've come up with a solution using AutoHotkey. Compile the script and then run the executable. Your IP address will be quickly copied to the clipboard! *This takes the first address from the the output of `ipconfig /all`. If you need help customizing the script, just let me know. :)*

### Download:

[http://ahk.igalvez.net/GetIPv4.exe, 784 KB, Windows 7](http://ahk.igalvez.net/GetIPv4.exe)

```
Clipboard =

myCommand = ipconfig /all | find "IPv4" | clip

Run cmd.exe
Send %myCommand%{Enter}
Sleep, 500
Send exit{Enter}

myString = %Clipboard%

StringReplace, myString, myString, %A_Space%, , All
StringReplace, myString, myString, IPv4Address...........:, , All
StringReplace, myString, myString, (Preferred), , All

StringSplit, myLines, myString, `r`n

Clipboard = %myLines1%

ExitApp
```

Comment: Wow! 2 minds think alike!  I too figured that an AutoHotKey command would be an easy way to run this... (I'm going to post my code as well)

Comment: @iglvzx, I mean if I was going to download something anyway, why not download a [**proper**](http://superuser.com/a/382360/78897) tool that does the **exact** thing the question wanted?

Answer (score 2):

While all the other options will work, if you need to get your IP address that often, I would have a dedicated program running just to deliver it to you.
For instance, I use a desktop gadget that displays my IP address.

This one, for instance, will display your IP address:
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/gr/system-monitor-gadget.htm

I also know there has to be a program somewhere that will sit in your system tray and feed you your ip address whenever you click on it.

Or maybe you could use a firefox/chrome extension.

 Hundreds of ways this could be done. Just use your imagination.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't get your IP address but does solve your underlying problem:

Install [Apple Bonjour for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999) on the machines you use, and you can reach the websites on them as http://[machinename].local/. Apple Bonjour uses the [ZeroConf](http://www.zeroconf.org/) networking standards to resolve hosts in the .local domain without any kind of central server. It's built in to Mac OS, and there is a linux implementation included in most distros called Avahi.

It even works over the 169.254.x.x link local IP addresses you get that usually mean your computer has failed to get an IP address with just a crossover cable between two machines.

I use it to allow windows-equipped colleagues to access test web sites hosted on my MacBook.

Comment: Install a full program (bloatware, with services that will autostart at every boot) on every machine? How can this be a good answer for the problem here?

Comment: @dema80 zeroconf is a very useful service. It solves this problem and many others.

Answer (score 0):

Install [realvnc](http://www.realvnc.com/) on your pc, hover your mouse over the task bar notification.

> RealVNC provides remote control software which lets you see and interact with desktop applications across any network.

Answer (score 0):

If you're cool, you'll keep a PowerShell window handy at all times. Then you can just run this script: http://pshscripts.blogspot.com/2009/01/get-ipaddressps1.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use JPSoft's TakeCommand (TCMD.exe) Command-line, there's an automatic variable:

%_IP

Be careful, though: It is a space-delimited list of every IP address.