# What is the IP of my Windows XP computer?

Tags: windows-xp, internet, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest method to determine my PC’s IP address (Windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/382265/fastest-method-to-determine-my-pcs-ip-address-windows)

On websites like whatismyip.org the IP we get is the IP of the modem we are using for internet connection.

How can I find out the permanent IP of my computer?

Comment: Do you mean the IP address on the LAN? A computer in a standard home network setup doesn't have a permanent IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a command window (start/run type `cmd` and hit enter)

In the command window type `ipconfig` and hit enter

You should see something like the following

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home    
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000    
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.6
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

This is the private IP address of that machine on the LAN.

When you go to whatismyip.org you are getting the public IP address assigned by your ISP

Comment: Just to clarify, the "IPv4 Address" is the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Open up cmd.exe and run `ipconfig` on it.

Just to clarify though,  when you're using DHCP, the ip address is part of a pool, and can change. The only way to have a 'permanant' IP address is to set it statically at your router.

I'd also note that in some scenarios, the IP address detected by sites such as whatismyip may be incorrect. Your ISP may use a proxy (in which case the proxy's address is detected in some situations), or use carrier grade nat. The best way to check an IP is at the device itself.