# Fastest way to find out IP address on Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, ip-address

What is the quickest way (in terms of necessary klicks or keystrokes from the empty desktop) of retrieving your own IP address in windows 10, specifically?

In Windows 7 and in case of wifi, you could get there rather quickly with wifi symbol task bar -> right click network -> status, but this possibility seems gone in Windows 10.

I seem forced to either use `ipconfig` (which is tedious if you have many interfaces e.g. from virtual machines) or open the *network and sharing center* which adds one window to the equation.

Is there a better, simpler way?

Comment: Many trigger happy negative voters around that prefer to stay anonymous..

Comment: No, it's not. Windows 7 and Windows 10 are not the same, and I don't see why so many people here seem to insist they are. Jusup's answer, for example, only works for Windows 10.

Comment: It's the same question and the same answers still apply (for the most part, if not completely). The marked duplicate is generalized to "Windows" (see tags and title), and also marked as a community Wiki (because it applies broadly to Windows in general). If you'd like to garner more/different/newer answers, consider earning some rep by helping others, and then post a bounty on the existing question. Or, if you'd like to add a new answer that's specific to Windows 10, feel free.

Comment: Please do not bothered with my answer, if you want to delete the question, please, at least you've got the answer for yourself, if others do not care about your question and concern, why do you have to care for others? I really do not mind if you remove the question. (+1 from me) i also do not care about down voting, it make somebody hurt feeling.

Comment: @Jusup It's not that we don't care about the question or the answers, it's simply that the question exists already. As for the downvotes (none of which I cast) I'd guess it's because it's phrased as "the fastest", and  that can be seen as subjective. Even if it gets closed as a duplicate, please leave it, as it can help other users find the duplicate quesiton.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have updated the question to make "fastest" a bit clearer. I couldn't think of another word for the title, though.

Comment: Sounds good. Still a dupe in my mind - but it takes more than just my vote to close this. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, If somebody come to this community, looking for help from their problem and then he/she received down vote rather than the answer because of 2 words in his/her phrases, think logically, do you know their feeling? Will they come again here? So, what is the point of this community? Helping  people or judging them? Do you think every people come here with their question know the rule of this community and know there's a duplicate question? especially with a new people or a person that have only 1 answer and 1 question record? Better for you to give an answer rather than down vote.

Comment: And better for you to direct them to previous similar question so their know the answer from the previous similar question.

Comment: @Jusup As I said, I didn't down-vote this question.  "And better for you to direct them to previous similar question so their know the answer from the previous similar question". That's exactly what I did, so I'm not sure what you're talking about.  Also, while we're not here to judge *people*, we are all here to judge *questions and answers*, hence the voting system. If you have questions or concerns about how the place works, perhaps check out http://meta.superuser.com.

Comment: @Jusup No worries mate, I'm over it, and Techie007 is not to blame anyway. I still disagree that it's a duplicate. On Linux you also wouldn't make one question "how can I do _something_ in X-Windows" and then require all similar questions but with regards to Gnome, KDE and other desktops to be incorporated into it. It's the same here, there are many similarities between the MS Windows version but you proved that there also are differences well worth knowing. So, let's just leave it at that.. :)

Answer (score 4):

In other way at Windows 10, right click Start button, select Task Manager then select performance tab, select either Wi-Fi or Ethernet, you can see both IPv4 and IPv6 address.

Comment: Now, see, this is already an improvement.. thanks Jusup!

Comment: Your welcome, additionally you can also monitoring the upload and download speed in real time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a simpler way then pressing `WIN+R` followed by `cmd` and `ipconfig /all | findstr IPv4`...

This may be duplicate to this thread [fastest method to determin ip address](https://superuser.com/questions/382265/fastest-method-to-determine-my-pcs-ip-address-windows)

Comment: This is what I would recommend as it will show both the IPs, though the optional grep may not be the best approach, as it won't show which is which.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The question is indeed the same. But it's 3 years old and concerned Windows 7, not 10 which is why I wouldn't call it a duplicate.

Comment: By the way, even if I did it like this, I would still get multiple IP addresses (VM bridges). Anyway, I know how to script this myself (just add route to the equation) but I was hoping there is a simpler way, such as hovering over the network symbol or something else in a similar fashion.

Comment: No, From MS's perspective, IP addresses would confuse non-technical users (especially IPv6 addresses), so they keep that kind of thing under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You can [reactivate the Desktop Gadgets](https://superuser.com/a/948068/174557) and use the [Gadget Network Meter](http://addgadgets.com/network_meter/) to see the IP:

[image]

Comment: That's a cute app, thanks. I installed it on my Win7 machines right away and will try _gadgets revived_ on Win10.

Answer (score 0):

As an IMO inferior alternative to the other proposed solutions, there is an app in the Windows store called *[IP address](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/ip-address/9wzdncrfhvf3)*. It just displays the internal and external IP address in a Windows 10 live tile.

[image: IP Address Live Tile]